# Trying to build Electric sheep from source

Tags: compiling, github

I am trying to build Electric sheep from source on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS following this page [github electric sheep compiling](https://github.com/scottdraves/electricsheep/wiki/Compiling) for building in Linux. I ran into some errors at the end. I think the problem is my understanding of the instructions.

I will present what I did:

1. Installed the packages mentioned.
2. Then I figured that I must download both [flame3](https://github.com/scottdraves/flam3) and [electricsheep](https://github.com/scottdraves/electricsheep) github files and unpack them.
3. Then I did ./configure; make; sudo make install inside flame3 directory. Everything went fine.
4. Then I investigated a little bit and figured that «Checkout client source...» may refer to the svn checkout command. I figure that this command can compare a directory with the code at github. But as I just downloaded the github code it should be up to date.
5. Inside electricsheep-master/client_generic I ran ./autogen.sh and ./configure which gave me no errors but running make gave a lot of errors,

```
~/electricsheep-master/client_generic$ make
Making all in Client
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/tarquinio/electricsheep-master/client_generic/Client'
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"electricsheep\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"electricsheep\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.7b33-svn\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"electricsheep\ 2.7b33-svn\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"http://code.google.com/p/electricsheep/issues/list\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"electricsheep\" -DVERSION=\"2.7b33-svn\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DUSE_NEW_FFMPEG_API=1 -DHAVE_LIBBOOST_THREAD=1 -DHAVE_LIBBOOST_FILESYSTEM=1 -DHAVE_LIBBOOST_SYSTEM=1 -DHAVE_LIBTINYXML=1 -DHAVE_LIBGLUT=1 -DHAVE_LIBGL=1 -DHAVE_LIBRT=1 -I.  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local/share/locale"\" -I .. -iquote ../DisplayOutput/OpenGL -I ../Common -I ../DisplayOutput -I ../DisplayOutput/Renderer -I ../Common/Math -I ../ContentDecoder -I ../TupleStorage -I ../ContentDownloader -I ../lua5.1/src -I ../Client -I ../Networking -I ../tinyXml  -DLINUX_GNU=1 -DSHAREDIR=\"/usr/local/share/electricsheep/\" -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/libgtop-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/lua5.1   -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/lua5.1   -lrt -lz -lGL -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -Wno-write-strings -DHAVE_AVC_VID2=1 -g -O2 -MT ShaderGL.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ShaderGL.Tpo -c -o ShaderGL.o `test -f '../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp' || echo './'`../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp: In destructor ‘virtual DisplayOutput::CShaderGL::~CShaderGL()’:
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:41:3: error: ‘glDeleteObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glDeleteObjectARB( m_VertexShader );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:41:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glDeleteTextures’
   glDeleteObjectARB( m_VertexShader );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glDeleteTextures
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:44:3: error: ‘glDeleteObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glDeleteObjectARB( m_FragmentShader );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:44:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glDeleteTextures’
   glDeleteObjectARB( m_FragmentShader );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glDeleteTextures
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:47:3: error: ‘glDeleteObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glDeleteObjectARB( m_Program );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:47:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glDeleteTextures’
   glDeleteObjectARB( m_Program );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glDeleteTextures
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool DisplayOutput::CShaderGL::Bind()’:
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:55:2: error: ‘glUseProgramObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
  glUseProgramObjectARB( m_Program );
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool DisplayOutput::CShaderGL::Unbind()’:
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:82:2: error: ‘glUseProgramObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
  glUseProgramObjectARB( 0 );
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool DisplayOutput::CShaderGL::Build(const char*, const char*)’:
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:128:14: error: ‘glCreateProgramObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
  m_Program = glCreateProgramObjectARB();
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:133:20: error: ‘glCreateShaderObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
   m_VertexShader = glCreateShaderObjectARB( GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB );
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:136:3: error: ‘glShaderSourceARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glShaderSourceARB( m_VertexShader, strIndex + 1, shaderStrings, NULL );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:136:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glShadeModel’
   glShaderSourceARB( m_VertexShader, strIndex + 1, shaderStrings, NULL );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glShadeModel
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:137:3: error: ‘glCompileShaderARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glCompileShaderARB( m_VertexShader );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:138:3: error: ‘glGetObjectParameterivARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glGetObjectParameterivARB( m_VertexShader, GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB, &vsResult );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:138:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glGetTexParameteriv’
   glGetObjectParameterivARB( m_VertexShader, GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB, &vsResult );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glGetTexParameteriv
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:140:4: error: ‘glAttachObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glAttachObjectARB( m_Program, m_VertexShader );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:144:3: error: ‘glGetInfoLogARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glGetInfoLogARB( m_VertexShader, sizeof(infoLog) - static_cast<size_t>(infoLogPos), &len, infoLog + infoLogPos );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:144:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glGetIntegerv’
   glGetInfoLogARB( m_VertexShader, sizeof(infoLog) - static_cast<size_t>(infoLogPos), &len, infoLog + infoLogPos );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glGetIntegerv
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:154:22: error: ‘glCreateShaderObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
   m_FragmentShader = glCreateShaderObjectARB( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB );
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:157:3: error: ‘glShaderSourceARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glShaderSourceARB( m_FragmentShader, strIndex + 1, shaderStrings, NULL );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:157:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glShadeModel’
   glShaderSourceARB( m_FragmentShader, strIndex + 1, shaderStrings, NULL );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glShadeModel
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:158:3: error: ‘glCompileShaderARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glCompileShaderARB( m_FragmentShader );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:159:3: error: ‘glGetObjectParameterivARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glGetObjectParameterivARB( m_FragmentShader, GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB, &fsResult );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:159:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glGetTexParameteriv’
   glGetObjectParameterivARB( m_FragmentShader, GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB, &fsResult );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glGetTexParameteriv
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:161:4: error: ‘glAttachObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glAttachObjectARB( m_Program, m_FragmentShader );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:165:3: error: ‘glGetInfoLogARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glGetInfoLogARB( m_FragmentShader, sizeof(infoLog) - static_cast<size_t>(infoLogPos), &len, infoLog + infoLogPos );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:165:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glGetIntegerv’
   glGetInfoLogARB( m_FragmentShader, sizeof(infoLog) - static_cast<size_t>(infoLogPos), &len, infoLog + infoLogPos );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glGetIntegerv
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:174:3: error: ‘glLinkProgramARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glLinkProgramARB( m_Program );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:174:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glHistogram’
   glLinkProgramARB( m_Program );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glHistogram
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:175:3: error: ‘glGetObjectParameterivARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glGetObjectParameterivARB( m_Program, GL_OBJECT_LINK_STATUS_ARB, &linkResult );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:175:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glGetTexParameteriv’
   glGetObjectParameterivARB( m_Program, GL_OBJECT_LINK_STATUS_ARB, &linkResult );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glGetTexParameteriv
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:176:3: error: ‘glGetInfoLogARB’ was not declared in this scope
   glGetInfoLogARB( m_Program, sizeof(infoLog) - static_cast<size_t>(infoLogPos), &len, infoLog + infoLogPos );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:176:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘glGetIntegerv’
   glGetInfoLogARB( m_Program, sizeof(infoLog) - static_cast<size_t>(infoLogPos), &len, infoLog + infoLogPos );
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   glGetIntegerv
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:184:4: error: ‘glUseProgramObjectARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUseProgramObjectARB( m_Program );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:198:5: error: ‘glGetActiveUniformARB’ was not declared in this scope
     glGetActiveUniformARB( m_Program, i, maxLength, &length, &size, &type, name );
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:198:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘glActiveTextureARB’
     glGetActiveUniformARB( m_Program, i, maxLength, &length, &size, &type, name );
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     glActiveTextureARB
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:203:23: error: ‘glGetUniformLocationARB’ was not declared in this scope
      GLint location = glGetUniformLocationARB( m_Program, name );
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:209:6: error: ‘glUniform1i’ was not declared in this scope
      glUniform1i( location, pos/*nSamplers*/ );
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:209:6: note: suggested alternative: ‘Uniform’
      glUniform1i( location, pos/*nSamplers*/ );
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      Uniform
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:255:64: error: ‘glGetUniformLocationARB’ was not declared in this scope
        m_Uniforms[ name ] = new CShaderUniformGL( name, eType, glGetUniformLocationARB( m_Program, name ), size );
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:291:4: error: ‘glUseProgram’ was not declared in this scope
    glUseProgram( GL_NONE );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:291:4: note: suggested alternative: ‘m_Program’
    glUseProgram( GL_NONE );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    m_Program
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool DisplayOutput::CShaderUniformGL::SetData(void*, uint32)’:
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:314:53: error: ‘glUniform1fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Float ] = (void *)glUniform1fvARB;
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:315:54: error: ‘glUniform2fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Float2 ] = (void *)glUniform2fvARB;
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:316:54: error: ‘glUniform3fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Float3 ] = (void *)glUniform3fvARB;
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:317:54: error: ‘glUniform4fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Float4 ] = (void *)glUniform4fvARB;
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:318:51: error: ‘glUniform1ivARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Int ] = (void *)glUniform1ivARB;
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:319:52: error: ‘glUniform2ivARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Int2 ] = (void *)glUniform2ivARB;
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:320:52: error: ‘glUniform3ivARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Int3 ] = (void *)glUniform3ivARB;
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:321:52: error: ‘glUniform4ivARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Int4 ] = (void *)glUniform4ivARB;
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:326:55: error: ‘glUniformMatrix2fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Matrix2 ] = (void *)glUniformMatrix2fvARB;
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:326:55: note: suggested alternative: ‘eUniform_Matrix2’
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Matrix2 ] = (void *)glUniformMatrix2fvARB;
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                       eUniform_Matrix2
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:327:55: error: ‘glUniformMatrix3fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Matrix3 ] = (void *)glUniformMatrix3fvARB;
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:327:55: note: suggested alternative: ‘eUniform_Matrix3’
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Matrix3 ] = (void *)glUniformMatrix3fvARB;
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                       eUniform_Matrix3
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:328:55: error: ‘glUniformMatrix4fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Matrix4 ] = (void *)glUniformMatrix4fvARB;
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:328:55: note: suggested alternative: ‘eUniform_Matrix4’
   g_UniformFunctionList[ eUniform_Matrix4 ] = (void *)glUniformMatrix4fvARB;
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                       eUniform_Matrix4
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void DisplayOutput::CShaderUniformGL::Apply()’:
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:385:4: error: ‘glUniform1fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniform1fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:388:4: error: ‘glUniform2fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniform2fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:391:4: error: ‘glUniform3fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniform3fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:394:4: error: ‘glUniform4fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniform4fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:399:4: error: ‘glUniform1ivARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniform1ivARB( m_Index, m_Size, (const GLint *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:403:4: error: ‘glUniform2ivARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniform2ivARB( m_Index, m_Size, (const GLint *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:407:4: error: ‘glUniform3ivARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniform3ivARB( m_Index, m_Size, (const GLint *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:411:4: error: ‘glUniform4ivARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniform4ivARB( m_Index, m_Size, (const GLint *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:414:4: error: ‘glUniformMatrix2fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniformMatrix2fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, GL_TRUE, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:414:4: note: suggested alternative: ‘eUniform_Matrix2’
    glUniformMatrix2fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, GL_TRUE, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    eUniform_Matrix2
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:417:4: error: ‘glUniformMatrix3fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniformMatrix3fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, GL_TRUE, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:417:4: note: suggested alternative: ‘eUniform_Matrix3’
    glUniformMatrix3fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, GL_TRUE, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    eUniform_Matrix3
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:420:4: error: ‘glUniformMatrix4fvARB’ was not declared in this scope
    glUniformMatrix4fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, GL_TRUE, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../DisplayOutput/OpenGL/ShaderGL.cpp:420:4: note: suggested alternative: ‘eUniform_Matrix4’
    glUniformMatrix4fvARB( m_Index, m_Size, GL_TRUE, (const GLfloat *)m_pData );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    eUniform_Matrix4
Makefile:751: recipe for target 'ShaderGL.o' failed
make[1]: *** [ShaderGL.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tarquinio/electricsheep-master/client_generic/Client'
Makefile:513: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Sorry for the long code.

I belive my mistake could be in understanding the «Checkout client source..» statement but otherwise I am clueless. I am still learning more about linux and overall computing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that official [download page](https://electricsheep.org/linux/) has a link to [`ppa:ichthyo/zeug` PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ichthyo/+archive/ubuntu/zeug?field.series_filter=bionic) which has binary packages for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and

> Note Electricsheep: all versions >= 3.0.2 are capable of running "gold sheep"

So you have to install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ichthyo/zeug
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install electricsheep
```

Comment: That's a good alternative. I ignored that method because they said «It has been packaged for Debian and Ubuntu, but those versions are out of date and cannot download Gold Sheep.»